# Effect click on button and open div with animation e change content and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how i can create effect like image?

[image]

when i click on the button...div open with effect animation and image and content change.

I would not know how to begin ... or explain.

Comment: Please make a start and show us what you have tried. You already seem to have/look at the right tools/setup. Provide jsfiddle with your work so far..[mcve]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=xnbBIpvBFB

I dont know how open div content1 with animation when i click on button1, and change header image.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v0of3gbp/ link work